# Target mean encoding function returning error

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to write a function that given a categorical variable and new variable name as inputs, add a new variable to the dataset with that categorical variable target mean encoded. Here's what I'm trying to do in the context of the `iris` dataset:

```
data("iris")
set.seed(25)
iris$target <- sample(0:1,150, replace = TRUE)

lookup <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Species_tme = mean(target))
iris <- left_join(iris, lookup)


> lookup
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    Species_tme
  <fct>            <dbl>
1 setosa            0.46
2 versicolor        0.56
3 virginica         0.62

> str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ target      : int  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ Species_tme : num  0.46 0.46 0.46 0.46 0.46 0.46 0.46 0.46 0.46 0.46 ...
```

But when put into a function:

```
tme <- function(var, new.name){
  lookup <- iris %>%
    group_by(var) %>%
    summarise(new.name = mean(target))
  iris <<- left_join(iris, lookup)
}

> tme(Species, Species_tme2)
 Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `var` is not found
```

Not sure what's going on here. Probably something trivial. Also, if there's a function already out there that does this, pointing me to that would work too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your function working, you need to embrace the variable with `{{`. For more infos, have a look at how to program with dplyr: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

```
tme <- function(var, new.name){
    lookup <- iris %>%
        group_by({{var}}) %>%
        summarise(new.name = mean(target))
    iris <<- left_join(iris, lookup)
}
```

---

Additionally, using `group_by` and `mutate` should give you what you want without the `lookup` and `join`:

```
lookup <- iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(Species_tme = mean(target))
iris2 <- left_join(iris, lookup)

iris3 <- iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    mutate(Species_tme = mean(target))

> all_equal(iris2, iris3)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can change the function to use `ensym` and `:=`

```
tme <- function(var, new.name){
   new.name <- rlang::as_string(ensym(new.name))
  lookup <- iris %>%
      group_by(!! ensym(var)) %>%
     summarise(!!new.name := mean(target, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
    iris <- left_join(iris, lookup)
    iris
  }
```